# My Software dll patches are not updated on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dll, patch

I have an existing files on windows 10 (dll,.exe,.msi) which I am trying to update by sending some patches. But the issue is during update if any of the file is being used, and I am trying to update that file by replacing it with new updated file , windows is prompting a delete file popup for the existing file.If we say yes it is showing as successfully deleted but it is not deleted till the last user releases the file .After that new updated file is not replaced in that place.

Edit: The poster has indicated in a comment that his problem relates to registered DLLs.

Comment: " I am trying to update by sending some patches" what patches, please explain.

Comment: How are you pushing these updates out exactly?

Comment: patches of my software - bunch of .exes push to client

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I replace an in use DLL?

> **Dynamic-Link Library Updates**
>
> It is sometimes necessary to replace a DLL with a newer version.
>   Before replacing a DLL, perform a version check to ensure that you are
>   replacing an older version with a newer version. It is possible to
>   replace a DLL that is in use. The method you use to replace DLLs that
>   are in use depends on the operating system you are using. On Windows
>   XP and later, applications should use [Isolated Applications and
>   Side-by-side Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408052(v=vs.85).aspx).
>
> It is not necessary to restart the computer if you perform the
>   following steps:
>
> - Use the `MoveFileEx` function to rename the DLL being replaced. Do not specify `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED`, and make sure the renamed file
>     is on the same volume that contains the original file. You could also
>     simply rename the file in the same directory by giving it a different
>     extension.
> - Copy the new DLL to the directory that contains the renamed DLL. All applications will now use the new DLL.
> - Use `MoveFileEx` with `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` to delete the renamed DLL.
>
> Before you make this replacement, applications will use the original
>   DLL until it is unloaded. After you make the replacement, applications
>   will use the new DLL. When you write a DLL, you must be careful to
>   ensure that it is prepared for this situation, especially if the DLL
>   maintains global state information or communicates with other
>   services. If the DLL is not prepared for a change in global state
>   information or communication protocols, updating the DLL will require
>   you to restart the computer to ensure that all applications are using
>   the same version of the DLL.

Source [Dynamic-Link Library Updates (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682604(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

> **How to replace in-use files at Windows restart**
>
> This article describes another method you can use to replace files
>   that are in use by Windows. This method uses the registry to replace a
>   file at startup, before the file is accessed by Windows.
>
> The following steps demonstrate how to replace the Win32k.sys file in
>   the `%SystemRoot%\System32` folder with the Win32k.sys file located in
>   the C:\Temp folder. You can use variations of this method to replace
>   any file if your installation of Windows is bootable.
>
> 1. Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).
> 2. Locate the following key in the Windows registry:
>
>    - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
> 3. Create a new value by using the following information:
>
>    - Value name: PendingFileRenameOperations
>    - Data type : `REG_MULTI_SZ`
>    - Value data: \??\c:\temp\win32k.sys !\??\c:\winnt\system32\win32k.sys
>    - Note that the value data is typed on two separate lines.
> 4. Quit Registry Editor.
> 5. Restart the computer.

Source [How to replace in-use files at Windows restart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/181345/how-to-replace-in-use-files-at-windows-restart)

Comment: This does not work for registered dlls.

Comment: @harrymc Then the user should update his question, which makes no mention of registered DLLs.

Comment: It is in the comments, but I did it now for him.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to replace a DLL is :

- Rename the DLL file
- Store the new DLL file under the correct name
- The renamed file becomes deletable when it's no longer in use.

For registered DLLs, you must un-register them in-place and register the new
version.
The un-registration process (when done with an installer) will detect in-use
DLLs and warn you that you need to reboot. Plus, this also means that the DLLs
can't be loaded (once unregistered) while you are copying new files or
registering new files.

You should therefore distribute your patch as an installer.
For example you could use the free
[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).
When I used it last, you needed to set the attributes of the DLLs
to be installed to do registration and re-registration.
The process will then be automatic with no special programming required
on your side.

If you cannot distribute your patch as an installer, you should set it
as run-once on startup and require a reboot.
For more information see the article
[Run a Program Only Once when you Boot Into Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/run-program-only-once-when-windows-is-booted-up/),
which requires some registry work.

Comment: harrymc we are talking about the registered dll's

Comment: @sams You made no mention these DLLs were registered.  Those only apply to COM libraries anyways.

Comment: @sams: I added a part for registered DLLs.